# Setting state after callback with json data

Tags: reactjs, callback, state, react-hooks

I'm receiving a callback from axios after a post request. The callback contains data that I need to use. I want add the callback json data my existing state - but after googling I learnt that callbacks + usestate hook doesn't work together well.

```
const [party, setParty] = useState("")

const SubmitParty = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    const PartyData = {
        party: party,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        number: number
    }

    axios.post(
        '/api/new/party',
        {
            party: party,
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            email: email,
            number: number
        },
        {
            params: {
                "secret_token": logged.token
            }
        }
    ).then(res => {


    var user = res.data.data;
    console.log(user); //I can see the response here and the array I want.

    setParty(user);

     console.log(party); // returns just a blank line. Expected to be same as user



        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            alert("Oops something went wrong. If this problem continues, please contact support asap!")
        });
}
```

I tried using a useeffect afterwards, but it's a catch 22, cause I need the state to deal with with in in useeffect accurately.

Comment: `setState` is `async` you are expecting synchronous behavior from it. By using `setParty(user);` it will re-render component and your stuff should take in new updated state. Is that not working?

Comment: As @Rikin says in the above comment `useState` is async so you will have to check in `useEffect` if you want to log the updated state but it should already re-render your components on the page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `useEffect` like this your component will send the API request and update `party` when it resolves.

```
const [party, setParty] = useState("");

useEffect(e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const PartyData = {
    party: party,
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
    number: number
  };

  axios
    .post(
      "/api/new/party",
      {
        party: party,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        number: number
      },
      {
        params: {
          secret_token: logged.token
        }
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      var user = res.data.data;
      console.log(user); //I can see the response here and the array I want.

      setParty(user);

      console.log(party); // returns just a blank line. Expected to be same as user
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      alert(
        "Oops something went wrong. If this problem continues, please contact support asap!"
      );
    });
});
```

By default this will run on every render. If you want the effect to run only once then you should set `useEffect`'s 2nd parameter to be an empty array, or if you only want it to run when a specific few items change then you can put those in the array.